# SQL Join same table on DateTime comparing Today and a previous entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Info` collects data.

```
DOEntry   |  StoreID  | UpcCode | QN  | DTOEntry
26-02-15  |     3     | 366     | 16  | 2-26-15 12:21 PM
26-02-15  |     3     | 373     | 8   | 2-26-15 12:21 PM
25-02-15  |     3     | 366     | 16  | 2-25-15 1:34 PM
25-02-15  |     3     | 373     | 6   | 2-25-15 1:34 PM
23-02-15  |     3     | 366     | 2   | 2-23-15 1:51 PM
23-02-15  |     3     | 373     | 12  | 2-23-15 1:51 PM
19-02-15  |     3     | 366     | 14  | 2-19-15 12:41 PM
19-02-15  |     3     | 373     | 10  | 2-19-15 12:41 PM
18-02-15  |     3     | 366     | 16  | 2-18-15 12:17 PM
18-02-15  |     3     | 373     | 6   | 2-18-15 12:17 PM
17-02-15  |     3     | 366     | 26  | 2-17-15 12:18 PM
17-02-15  |     3     | 373     | 6   | 2-17-15 12:18 PM
```

What I'm trying to achieve is comparing a `UpcCode` of `StoreID` with its previous record using `DTOEntry`. To gets it New `QN` verious its previous `QN` (not necessary yesterday eg. `24-02-15` doesn't exist

Desired output

```
DOEntry_new|  StoreID | UpcCode | QN_new | QN_previous
26-02-15   |    3     | 366     | 16     |  16
26-02-15   |    3     | 373     | 8      |  6
25-02-15   |    3     | 366     | 16     |  2
25-02-15   |    3     | 373     | 6      |  12
23-02-15   |    3     | 366     | 2      |  14
23-02-15   |    3     | 373     | 12     |  10
19-02-15   |    3     | 366     | 14     |  16
19-02-15   |    3     | 373     | 10     |  6
```

Can any one suggest is this even possible. I tried `inner join` but I can compare only today and yesterday but that condition is not possible

Thanks

Comment: Is the previous entry always 1 day earlier or could it be more?

Comment: What happened to the records on the 17th and 18th?

Comment: @DavidG not it could be more example no record for `24-02-15` so anything previous

Comment: @GordonLinoff they exist .. I just didn't write them, I will write them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `lag()`.  In SQL Server 2008, the most reasonable ways correlated subquery or `apply`.  Here is an example:

```
select i.*, p.qn as qn_previous
from info i cross apply
     (select top 1 i2.*
      from info i2
      where i2.storeid = i.storeid and i2.upcode = i.upcode and
            i2.doentry < i.doentry
      order by i2.doentry desc
     ) p;
```